# Sharing data between an IOS Utility Application views

Tags: ios, global-variables, data-sharing

I have created a very basic application using the Utility Application template in Xcode 4.2 in which I want an integer variable obtained from a slider or text field in my FlipsideViewController available in my MainViewController.

I have been searching for hour on global variables but can't find a nice simple answer that works for my specific case.

Please help

(note: I am very new at developing for IOS and objective C. Dumb your answer down for me as much as you are capable!)

Thanks a lot

The following is a basic version of my code showing what I want to do.

FlipSideViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderValueOnFlipside;

@end
```

FlipSideViewController.m

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipsideViewController
@synthesize sliderValueOnFlipside;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setSliderValueOnFlipside:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

- (IBAction)sliderChange:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *) sender;
    int var = [slider value];

    sliderValueOnFlipside.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider Value is %d",var];
}

@end
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderValueOnMain;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize sliderValueOnMain;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    sliderValueOnMain.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider Value from flipside is %d", var];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setSliderValueOnMain:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

@end
```

I can easily get the value of the slider to be displayed on the flipside view however I also want that value displayed on the main view.

Comment: If you post some code it will be easier for people to formulate pertinent answers.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are generally frowned upon in polite programming circles.

If you want a method in MainViewController to react to a change in state in FlipsideViewController, then you could make MVC a delegate of FVC, and have FVC call a method on MVC when the value changes.

There's a good explanation of the delegate design pattern here: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html